# why cant you access first div element of body like document.body.div[0] in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can do `document.body.childNodes[1]` but why not this 'document.body.div[1]'. How document is special?

Sorry if i am missing something.

Following this logic,and document is not special, body should have been only accessible through like this.

`document.childNodes[1]` or so. Assuming div body is second element.

Why does it work like this.

document.body.etc << i can do this but...

document.body.div << not this. Instead this...

document.body.childNodes[1] << Works given div is 2nd element!

document.childNodes[1] << then why is it not the only way to acces body given its 2nd element thus [1].

document.body.div.p << i want to do this, by my understanding of html object model it should be possible.

Comment: If your concern is that index `0` is giving you a text node, you can use `.children[0]` instead, which only returns elements.

Comment: Explained what i wanted to ask really, that was really unclear before.

Comment: Providing `document.body` is simple because it's a default element, and there can be only one. I would imagine that for every element to maintain a unique collection for each different type of its children, it would require a good bit of overhead. There are a couple exceptions. A `select` element has an `.options` collection, a `table` has a `.tHead`, a `.tFoot` and a `.tBodies` collection. Also, each of those has a `.rows` collection, and each row has a `.cells` collection.

Comment: ok so why can't you do this document.body.div[1] and CAN do this document.body.childNodes[1]

Comment: *"I would imagine that for every element to maintain a unique collection for each different type of its children, it would require a good bit of overhead."* ...ultimately it doesn't matter. You can't do it. The functionality isn't there. If you want to change it, convince the standards board to include you at the next meeting. http://www.w3.org/

Comment: so for some reason this 'functionality' only exists for direct children of 'document' element. I still feel this is weird.

Comment: It'll work for any element, not just for children of `document`, but it won't work for text nodes since text nodes by nature don't have descendants.

Comment: so how can you do this document.body.div

Comment: Please describe in detail what you want. Are you saying you want a collection of all the div children nested directly under `document.body`? If so, make a function that receives an element and a tag name, iterates the children of the element, pushes the ones that match the tag name into an array, and returns the array.

Answer (score 1):

`document.childNodes[0]` will return the first tag in the whole document, whereas `document.body.childNodes[0]` will return the first tag under the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure about the structure of your html but:

`document.childNodes[0]` get's you the first node in the html. (here on stackoverflow for example that's `<!DOCTYPE html>`

If you want to get the body through traversing this way you can do:

`document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2]` (get's you the body for here on this page)

Basically you need to take care of the element's sequence.
On the contrast traversing the DOM with the named elements is quite different.
I hope this helps.

Comment: document.childNodes[0] gives you <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Hehe, yeah sorry, my bad :) - Fixed.

Comment: i know that you can go inside like childNOdes[1] etc. But why cant you go like document.body.p[0].text instead you have to do document.body.childNodes[1].childNodes[0] and if it is like it is then why can you do straight for body...Why can you write document.body instead of not only document.childNodes[1]